# How to convert Nvarchar to datetime in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I was working on a timestamp query in SQL Server and have a column of data type `nvarchar` with values like:

```
01 02:52:12 , 01 03:00:25 ,01 03:08:09 ,01 03:35:20
```

Here

- `1` = Day of the month or date of the month
- `02:52:12` = Time of the day

All these are quoted as `NVARCHAR`.

My end goal is to extract DAY (using one query) in order to do cohort analysis, and then find the time difference between 2 timestamps.

In order to find `DATEDIFF` or any other date function.

I get an error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

while importing the data from Excel; I tried to change the datatype but then it won't import the data.

I have used

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(Minute, [name 1], [name 2]) AS time
FROM table name
```

Comment: I think you might need to know WHICH month. For example, the difference between 28th FEB and 01 March is not the same as e.g. the difference between 28th March and 03 April. If you can guarantee that e.g. the days will ALWAYS be either the same or consecutive you MIGHT have some options. Come to think of it - you might have to know which YEAR as well, since leap years in FEB have 29 days.

Comment: hi , the data is given in just this form " 01 02:52:12 , 01 03:00:25 ,01 03:08:09 ,01 03:35:20"  now what I tried doing is that I used text to coloums function in excel and separated 01 in to 1 coloum and separated  02:52:12 into another one , but when I Import this into Sql server , the day of month shows as 01 but then time now has 1899-01-01 02:52:12 as the result , all I want to do is calculate delivery time difference between starting and ending points

Comment: will your data definitely only ever have a difference in the time component and not the date? could it ever do something like '01 23:59:50' to '02 00:05:15'?

Comment: Please don't repost questions, if your question is closed there is an edit feature you can use to improve the question.

Comment: I know that the moderators don't deem this to be a well-phrased question; but having dealt with clocking systems etc. before with "imperfect data", I am accustomed to these scenarios; I "Get" your question. I have some boiler plate code for you for this algorithm, but can't post here any more.  - feel free to contact me at gerhard.diedericks@gmail.com if you want me to send you the SQL. Good luck, friend.